# Python : AttributeError

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I get an AttributeError I can't seem to work out.
I'm working with two classes.

The first class goes something like that.

```
class Partie:
    def __init__(self):
        # deleted lines
        self.interface = Interface(jeu=self)

    def evaluerProposition(self):
        # computations
        self.interface.afficherReponse()
```

Introducing second class (in a separate file).

```
class Interface:
    def __init__(self, jeu):
        self.jeu = jeu
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        # stuff

    def onClick(self, event):
        # talk
        self.jeu.evaluerProposition()

    def afficherReponse(self):
        # stuff
```

I start the whole thing by

```
partie = Partie()
```

All manipulations on my widget work fine until some click event causes

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1442, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Canard\Documents\My Dropbox\Python\AtelierPython\Mastermind\classeInterface.py", line 197, in clic
    self.jeu.evaluerProposition()
  File "C:\Users\Canard\Documents\My Dropbox\Python\AtelierPython\Mastermind\classeJeu.py", line 55, in evaluerProposition
    self.interface.afficherReponse()
AttributeError: 'Partie' object has no attribute 'interface'
```

I typed in the interpretor

```
>>> dir(partie)
```

and got a long list in return with 'interface' among the attributes.

Also typed

```
>>> partie.interface
<classeInterface.Interface object at 0x02C39E50>
```

so the attribute seems to exist.

Following the advice in some former post, I checked the instance names do not coincide with module names.
I am confused.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the fact that you're passing `self` in the constructor for `Partie` as an argument to `Interface()` isn't healthy...

Comment: @kren470 I don't think Python cares in which order you define classes.

Comment: @2rs2ts It does seem unhealthy indeed.
I created a third class `Master` with two attributes `interface` and `partie`. I could then link both objects by
    self.partie.interface = self.interface
    self.interface.partie = self.partie

Comment: Where do you use the `onClick` method? Can you show that code? My guess is, you're doing something like `Button(..., command=self.onClick())` (note the trailing `()` after the function name). If you are, you need to remove the `()` (eg: `Button(..., command=self.onClick`).

Comment: There is no obvious fault in this code. But you should post the code of the function `interface.afficherResponse`, since this is the one causing the error.

Comment: Can you add a print statement at the end of your `Partie.__init__` ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, in some code that you're not showing us, you're doing something like this:

```
self.some_button = tkinter.Button(..., command=self.interface.onClick())
```

Note the trailing `()` on `onClick()`. This would cause the `onClick` method to be called *at the time the button is created*, which is probably before your constructor is done constructing the instance of the `Partie` class.